# Оптимизация класса модели для представления

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, инспекция-кода

Я хочу сделать класс, который буду использовать в качестве модели в строго типизированном представлении в [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) приложении:

```
public class MaterialAssetDetails
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string ItemNumber {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string MeasureUnit {get;set;}
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}

    public MaterialAssetDetails(int id, string itemNumber, string Name,
        string measureUnit, decimal amount, decimal price)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.ItemNumber=itemNumber;
        //и так далее
    }
}
```

Назначение *этого*: отображение детальной информации о *материальном активе*.

**Что мне не нравится:** то количество параметров, которое необходимо передать в конструктор(и это еще не все свойства) для создания экземпляра объекта.

Подскажите как Вы поступаете с подобными классами?

P.S.: мне приходит  в голову только создание перегруженной версии конструктора без параметров `amount`, `price`:

```
public MaterialAssetDetails(int id, string itemNumber, string name, string measureUnit)
:this(id, itemNumber, name, measureUnit, 0,0)
{
}
```

Comment: pageObject шаблон не рассматриваете ?

Comment: @SeniorAutomator можете ответить чуть более подробно(я не слышал про такой патерн/шаблон), если не сложно на конкретном примере. заранее спасибо

Comment: А если просто убрать конструктор?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov у меня на текущий момент не определен конструктор, т.е. у меня код соответствует способу предложенному MarkShevcenko, но он мне не нравится что приходится помнить свойства необходимые к заполнению

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MaterialAssetDetails {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string ItemNumber {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string MeasureUnit {get;set;}
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}


    public MaterialAssetDetails(int id, string itemNumber)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.ItemNumber=itemNumber;

        //и так далее
    }

    public MaterialAssetDetails withName(string name){
        this.Name = name;
        return this;
    }

    public MaterialAssetDetails withName(string MeasureUnit){
        this.MeasureUnit = MeasureUnit;
        return this;
    }


    public MaterialAssetDetails withAmount(decimal Amount){
        this.Amount = Amount;
        return this;
    }

    public MaterialAssetDetails withPrice(decimal Price){
        this.Price = Price;
        return this;
    }


    static int Main(string[] args) {
        MaterialAssetDetails details = new MaterialAssetDetails(0, "0")
                .withAmount(0)
                .withName("name")
                .withPrice(0);
    }
}
```

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_model) и еще одна [статья](https://kreisfahrer.gitbooks.io/selenium-webdriver/content/page_object_pattern_arhitektura_testovogo_proekta/ispolzovanie_patterna_page_object.html)

вообще данный шаблон используют в других целях, но если вы не хотите много параметров в конструктор передавать

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку у вас все поля имеют не только геттеры, но и сеттеры, вы можете отказаться от конструктора совсем. Начиная с C# версии 4 можно инициализировать классы так:

```
public class MaterialAssetDetails
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string ItemNumber {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string MeasureUnit {get;set;}
    public decimal Amount {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
}

. . .

var details = new MaterialAssetDetails
{
    Id = model.Id,
    ItemNumber = model.ItemNumber,
    Name = model.Name,
    MeasureUnit = model.MeasuteUnit,
};
```

По сути это синтаксический сахар: компилятор сначала создаёт пустой экземпляр класса `MaterialAssetDetails`, а затем присваивает указанным свойствам указанные значения.

Альтернатива: использовать значения по умолчанию в конструкторе:

```
public MaterialAssetDetails(int id, string itemNumber, string Name,
    string measureUnit, decimal amount = 0m, decimal price = 0m)
{
    . . .
}
```

В этом случае вы тоже можете инициализировать только те поля, которые необходимо, остальные заполняя только в случае необходимости.

Наконец, если набор моделей и связанных с ними представлений достаточно большой, можно использовать что-то вроде библиотеки **AutoMapper**, которая позволяет копировать свойства с одинаковыми типами и именами.

Comment: предложенный Вами способ у меня на текущий момент, он мне не нравится что при создании экземпляра объекта мне приходится *помнить* какие свойства надо заполнять

Comment: Можно совмещать, то есть заполнять обязательные поля через конструктор, а не обязательные через инициализацию в фигурных скобках. Впрочем, я вашего проекта не знаю, так что сами выбирайте, какой способ лучше.